# Create folders in site pages - Possible?

Tags: folder, sitepages

Is there a way to sort these pages by folder? Site pages in site contents is looking a little cluttered. Not looking to add more columns. Its possible in a document library just not sure about site pages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible but you have to enable folders in advanced settings in the library settings.

Go to library in question > Library Settings > Advanced settings > Set 'Make "New Folder" command available?' to Yes and then click Ok.

You should now be able to create folders in the site pages library.

Comment: As @jim-parker points out: "You'd have to then copy the page to the appropriate folder, and then delete the original page, since there is no move option."

Answer (score 3):

The idea behind a publishing site is that you create subsites for sections or areas of your site. For example About Us, Products, Services, News. Since each sub site will have its own Pages library, you would then get natural page organization that way.

You can create folders like you mentioned, but it can affect your site navigation depending on if you are using managed navigation or structural navigation. The latter can't read pages in sub folders and populate the navigation accordingly.

Just a heads up in case that would affect your site.

Comment: To add to Heather's comment, you'll also find difficulty managing the pages, since by default the option to add a "News post" will store the page in the root of the current site pages library.  You'd have to then copy the page to the appropriate folder, and then delete the original page, since there is no move option.

Comment: Just a warning that by creating a subsite in SharePoint Modern, you lose the ability to inherit the Quick Launch menu from the parent site. There's an assumption that the subsite will have it's own local navigation rather than being a convenient organisational bucket just to put News in. See https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/175806/can-i-force-quick-launch-sidebar-links-from-home-page-to-all-sites-and-sub-sit#comment182897_175811

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off using a meta data column and organizing pages that way (preferably a managed property site column to aid search down the road). Users can select the appropriate category from page details when creating the page. A hard but good habit to enforce.